# How to Customise default Alert in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am trying to change the colour of Alert Buttons.

my alert like below.

```
await DisplayAlert("Question?", "Would you like to play a game", "Yes", "No");
```

I need to make `Yes` button `Red` both `Android` and `iOS`.

I need to get default alert view for both platform rather than creating a custom pop up.

is there any way to write a renderer for this?

Comment: Xamarin.Forms provide DisplayActionSheet method... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/pop-ups

Comment: Are there any update for this issue? If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to mark it as answer, it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need exact visual effect on both platforms you must write custom renderer, because DisplayAlert is not rendered by XF.

Comment: "If you need exact visual effect on both platforms you must write custom renderer, because DisplayAlert is not rendered by XF." Try to get your wording together :D

Comment: English is not my primary language, and I suppose you don't understand my answer.  I respect that. If you need explanation just ask in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Hello man hope to get nice day

in iOS you need to use MessageCenter wherever you need to display Dailog and subscribe it in ApprDelegate as following:

```
        UIAlertController vc = UIAlertController.Create("", titleWeSendFromMessageCenterArgs, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
        UIAlertAction action = UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null);
        vc.AddAction(action);

        vc.View.TintColor = UIColor.Red;//or whatever you want

        Window.RootViewController.PresentViewController(vc, true, null);
```

in Android you just change colorAccent in you style file in resource
hope to be useful.